# xmodmap clear modifier not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xkb

Trying to understand XKB and how to customize keyboard mappings, specially for modifiers.

A little experiment on disabling modifiers, leads to an unexpected result:

(1) Modifier maps before

```
$ xmodmap -pm
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

(2) Clear lock modifier

```
$ xmodmap -e 'clear Lock'
```

(3) Cleared ok

```
$  xmodmap -pm
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

I expected to disable CapsLock from setting the lock state, but it does't.
It works as usual, and using `xev` to see the key press events, I see that the lock flag still changes (`state 0x0` when CapsLock is off, `state 0x2` when on).

What is actually the `clear` command doing?

How can I detach keys(keycodes) to disable their function as modifiers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, CapsLock functionality is bound to keysym value of pressed key. To see mapping of keycodes to keysyms execute `xmodmap -pke`. The mapping of <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> (keycode 66) should be (`| grep 'keycode  66'`):

```
keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
```

You may play around a bit with `xev`. Read more at [ArchWiki: Xmodmap#Introduction](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap#Introduction).

> How can I detach keys(keycodes) to disable their function as
>   modifiers?

You need to change mapping of <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>.

- To disable <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, you need to unmap it:

  ```
  xmodmap -e 'keycode  66 = NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol'
  ```
- To enable <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, you need to map it again to default values:

  ```
  xmodmap -e 'keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock'
  ```

> What is actually the clear command doing?

It clears mapping of a modifier, not mapping of keycodes. More at [ArchWiki: Xmodmap#Modifier_keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap#Modifier_keys)

Comment: My desire behaviour is to only use CapsLock when the ShiftKey is pressed. With your suggestion now works! I was using VoidSymbol instad NoSymbol: `xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = VoidSymbol Caps_Lock'` With NoSymbol works as desired, VoidSymbol has no effect. Whats the difference between the two? Seem I can't find documentation about it